# Dynamically resizing div

Tags: html, resize

I'm working on my portfolio, and I'm making it all on one page, javascript based. My problem is, if I load in a different page, the div containing the content of the page doesn't resize.

http://portfolio.theadamgaskins.com/Portfolio/ Click "Death Worm" to see what I mean.

So, how do I make a div resize vertically to fit its content?

Comment: Your question is valid (+1), but your page is not (-1). You've added way too many inline styles with JavaScript, and you're not using <a> tags for your links (they don't need to make the page change, but they need to be there for accessibility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has nice tools to let you resize whatever you want: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Although you don't explicitly set the `#pageContent` height - I think whatever curvyCorners is - does

Comment: Oh, yep thats what the problem is. When I turn curvyCorners off it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your `div` id'd `pageContent` has a height.

Answer (score 0):

It should by default. Use Firefox with the Firebug extension, or Google-chrome, to debug dynamic pages, using the right-click "inspect element" feature.

Comment: I see you found the answer above, and that when you turned a feature off, it auto-resized. So the *default* is to auto-resize. My comment about Firebug was so that you could see directly what these functions do to your HTML.